# VBA to automatically print page ranges of a PDF

Tags: vba, pdf

At work, attached files size to email is limited to 10 Mo and because of many reasons :

- Outlook is the only way to share files
- I can only use the programs already installed

I am trying to create a VBA macro to :

- automatically split PDF bigger than 10 Mo by printing them into smaller files
- merge them on the other side

I know it is far from ideal (and many tools exists to do it), but I have no other options.

So far, it seems that I can only use PDFCreator and Adobe Reader for this task, as no other helpfull tools are deployed on my PC (mostly Office)... and I can not figure a way to use command line for printing range of pages.

I successfully created a working (very) inelegant macro, based on Shell commands and SendKeys VBA, basically emulating human interaction to print range A, then waiting for the job to be done, them printing range B, and so on... Among the many problems I should now solve :

- add protection to take into account machines with different processing power (replace my timings with file creation verification and detect if jobs are still running in the background)
- create a robust merging system when receiving the mail

Plus I am very dependant of the software versions installed, and I foresee a lot of issues with software updates/version if this macro is to be used by many people.

So this method doesn't have a bright futur for now, and unless I find an other way to solve this problem, I will probably give up and keep doing this manually (after all, if my employer doesn't provide better tool, I should not be expected to be as efficient as I could).

Have you any insight about how to cleverly solve this issue ?
(Yes, I already told my boss that working like this is a nightmare, but easy file exchange is not the priority).

Comment: Have you tried `http://www.onlinefreeware.net/pdf/Split.aspx`? or 'http://www.systotech.com/pdf-split.aspx'

Comment: @GMalc Thanks for your suggestion but our network is not connected to Internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using **7-zip** and its "-v" option using command line : I split my big file into binary smaller files and automatically create new mail with them as attachments.